# Duplication of id values in another column in same table django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am working on one python(django framework) project in which i have one user model which has 1000 users. I want to make one another column named priority id and need to put default id values in that priority id column accordingly (you can see it below).

| id | username | email | priority_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | abc@gmail.com | 1 |
| 2 | xyz | xyz@gmail.com | 2 |

ofcourse i can do it manually using admin panel but for 1000 users it is time consuming.

how do i change models.py or admin.py or something else to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.priority_id = self.id
    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: it throws an error..name self is not defined

Comment: Please share the error message. Note, this should be under the class in models.py.

Comment: i applied your second solution but it works only on the new entries not the existing one

Comment: Try to remove the old migrations and migrate again.

Comment: If needed you can handle existing instances through the shell. Open the shell and run for user in User.objects.all(): user.priority_key = user.id, user.save()

Comment: i can not remove old migrations...and i tried the last one from the shell..nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would ever want to do this, but you can achieve it by adding adding a BigAutoField to your user model. The field will then auto-increment the values for new users according to available ids.

In your models where you define the user, add following field.

```
priority_id = models.BigAutoField(null=False, unique=True)
```

Comment: i needed to do it because i didnt want to manipulate the main id column as it is connected with so many other operations. does your solution also insert data in existing rows or it is only for new entries?

Comment: Also it shows an error models cant have more than one autofield

Comment: @pratikahir, yes it would insert data for existing entries, but apparently it's not allowed to have two autofields in the same model (the automatically added pk autofield being the other). So I suggest you deal with it in the save method of the model as shown in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

well, i tried it using shell and it worked:

```
p = Users.objects.all()
for x in p:
    profile = Users.objects.get(pk=x.id)
    profile.priority_id= x.id
    profile.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this for me its working fine first you have to create with a default value and then use this function in views and just call once it will update the value as in id.

```
    def update_value(request):
        totaldata = modelsName.objects.all()
        for j in totaldata:
            
            modelsName.objects.filter(id=j.id).update(myid=j.id)
            
    return HttpResponse('Success')
```